# SQL Server - optional where clause - empty Table Valued Parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have three TVP - A, B and C

A is never empty. B or C can be empty.

```
AND
SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @A) -- First
AND
SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @B) -- Second -- Make this optional
AND
SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @C) -- Third -- Make this optional
```

I need to make the Second/Third condition optional. I have tried quite a lot of things like `case, (SELECT .. OR @B = null)`, but since these are table value parameters its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `OR`

```
AND
(
SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @A) -- First
OR
SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @B) -- Second -- Make this optional
OR
SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @C) -- Third -- Make this optional
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If only the second and third conditions are optional, then try this

```
AND SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @A) -- First

OR

(
    SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @B) -- Second -- Make this optional
    OR
    SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @C) -- Third -- Make this optional
)
```

Comment: they're not parameters.. they are table variables.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen and set stored procedures where the parameters are defaulted to NULL

```
@A int = NULL,
@B int = NULL,
@C int = NULL
```

The code behind will load in parameters, and @B and @C may or may not be loaded.

When you get to your `WHERE` clause, you put

```
SomeId IN (SELECT n FROM @A)
AND (SomeID IN (SELECT n FROM @B) OR @B IS NULL)
AND (SomeID IN (SELECT n FROM @C) OR @C IS NULL)
```

Notice the syntax; it is not `@B = NULL`, it is `@B IS NULL`

Comment: These are table valued parameters. This does not work.

Comment: @AseemGautam: I think DWF is on the right track.  Something like `SomeID IN (SELECT n FROM @A) AND (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @B) AND SomeID IN (SELECT n FROM @B))`...  Wouldn't that work for your purposes?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.*, a.N, b.N, c.N FROM MyTable m
INNER JOIN @A a
    ON a.N = m.SomeId
LEFT JOIN @B b
    ON b.N = m.SomeId
LEFT JOIN @C c
    ON c.N = m.SomeId
```

So you are trying to get all the records that match to a, and then if they match to b or c, then you can do something with them?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.  It starts off as the same query as the original, but for each of the two "optional" TVPs it adds a UNION ALL to select the "SomeId" ONLY IF there are now rows in that particular TVP. This keeps with the intent of using the TVP as a filter IF there are rows in it, else it does not filter out the row.

```
DECLARE @Main TABLE (ID INT);
INSERT INTO @Main (ID) VALUES (55);
INSERT INTO @Main (ID) VALUES (999);

DECLARE @TestA TABLE (Col1 INT);
INSERT INTO @TestA (Col1) VALUES (55);
INSERT INTO @TestA (Col1) VALUES (67855);
DECLARE @TestB TABLE (Col1 INT);
--INSERT INTO @TestB (Col1) VALUES (565);

SELECT tmp.ID
FROM @Main tmp
WHERE tmp.ID IN (SELECT Col1 FROM @TestA)
AND tmp.ID IN (
               SELECT Col1 FROM @TestB
               UNION ALL
               SELECT tmp.ID
               WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @TestB)
              )
```

The query (with the `INSERT INTO @TestB` commented out) returns the value of `55` since @TestB is "optional". But if you uncomment that `INSERT INTO @TestB`, then nothing is returned since @TestB does not contain the value `55`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much cleaner and equally as succinct to do the following:

```
;WITH AllowedIds_CTE (SomeId) AS (
    SELECT n from @A
    UNION
    SELECT n from @B
    UNION
    SELECT n from @C
)
SELECT * FROM SomeTable O
JOIN AllowedIds_CTE A
    ON O.SomeId = A.SomeId;
```

Multiple nested subqueries and `IN` operations are less readable and potentially less efficient than joins with CTEs/tables.

The CTE ([Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)) in this model can be replaced with an indexed temp table if performance is a concern, and `UNION` can be replaced with `UNION ALL` if you know your `n` values to be distinct across `@A`, `@B` and `@C`.